Applying for a UK visa while a US visa application is in administrative processing for five months
I am applying for UK visitor visa for study, while my US F1 visa is in administrative processing for 5 months and has no update.
On the UK visa application there is a question: Have you ever been refused a visa? It has options to answer as yes/no. What should be the proper answer?

From what you say the answer is not Yes. I would answer ‘No’ and provide a note along the lines of “applied for US F1 visa on DD/MM/YY, decision awaited”

Unless your U.S. visa has actually to your knowledge been refused, or you have been refused a visa to another country at some other point in the past, then the only answer can be 'No'. Taking a long time to process is NOT the equivalent to a refusal. I've personally had a visa take exactly as long as the longest suggested time possible and be approved on literally the last day.
